# Getting firebase is not defined on setting document in html/ javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

So, basically i am trying to save data in firebase an am getting the error "firebase is not defined"
my code:-

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js";
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: ""
      };
    
      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase                                                  // getting error over here
  .firestore()
  .collection("books")
  .add({
    title: "Of Mice and Men",
  })
  .then((ref) => {
    console.log("Added doc with ID: ", ref.id);
    // Added doc with ID:  ZzhIgLqELaoE3eSsOazu
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 9 of its JavaScript SDK, Firebase has switched to a new modular syntax where you import individual functions. You'll have to choose whether you want to use the new syntax, or continue using the previous syntax through its compatibility layer.

To [import the compatibility libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat), use:

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

To then switch to the new syntax, follow the instructions in the same [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade), and in the v9 tab of the [code samples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) in the rest of the documentation.